# How can I remove quoted string literals from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

I have a string:

> Hello "quoted string" and 'tricky"stuff' world

and want to get the string minus the quoted parts back. E.g.,

> Hello and world

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, so quoted strings can contain the "other" quote symbol. Can there also be escaped quotes like `"This is \"one\" string"`?

Comment: Do you need to support escaping the quote characters?  Also, this seems like a useless exercise -- should this be tagged homework?

Comment: @Kirk, I am 37 and gave up homework a long time ago. Sorry if my question didn't meet your high standards.

Comment: @Tim: Correct; One quoted string can contain the other quote. Escaped quotes will not appear.

Comment: What about "Don't stop believin' hold on to the feelin' streetlight people"? Are the missing gs on "believin'" and "feelin'" to be considered as delimiting an internal quotation? What about the apostrophe in the "don't"? Also, do you need to consider “round quotes”, or just "straight quotes"? My advice: write an *extremely careful and detailed specification* before you write any code.

Comment: @Eric. Thanks, but there is already a syntax checker beforehand that makes sure quotes balance.

Comment: @Andrew White: In your example, quotes don't balance

Comment: @Andrew, `I can't believe he didn't believe me.` The quotes balance and you would be left with `I cant believe me.`

Comment: @Matt: Yes they do. Every open quote (which itself is not enclosed in quotes of a different type) has a corresponding closing quote.

Comment: @Anthony. Yep, strange as it may seem, that's what I want

Comment: @Andrew White: Oh! that's a different balance to what I was expecting :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"([""'])# Match a quote, remember which one
    (?:      # Then...
     (?!\1)  # (as long as the next character is not the same quote as before)
     .       # match any character
    )*       # any number of times
    \1       # until the corresponding closing quote
    \s*      # plus optional whitespace
    ", 
    "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

will work on your example.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"([""'])# Match a quote, remember which one
    (?:      # Then...
     (?!\1)  # (as long as the next character is not the same quote as before)
     \\?.    # match any escaped or unescaped character
    )*       # any number of times
    \1       # until the corresponding closing quote
    \s*      # plus optional whitespace
    ", 
    "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

will also handle escaped quotes.

So it will correctly transform

```
Hello "quoted \"string\\" and 'tricky"stuff' world
```

into

```
Hello and world
```

Comment: I was just typing up something similar with just var `"\"[^\"]*\""` as my Regex string (i.e. `"[^"]*"` as the regex). Can you explain what yours is doing and why?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match any quoted strings with the string and replace them with the empty string. Use the `Regex.Replace()` method to do the pattern matching and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

In case, like me, you're afraid of regex, I've put together a functional way to do it, based on your example string. There's probably a way to make the code shorter, but I haven't found it yet.

```
private static string RemoveQuotes(IEnumerable<char> input)
{
    string part = new string(input.TakeWhile(c => c != '"' && c != '\'').ToArray());
    var rest = input.SkipWhile(c => c != '"' && c != '\'');
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(new string(rest.ToArray())))
        return part;
    char delim = rest.First();
    var afterIgnore = rest.Skip(1).SkipWhile(c => c != delim).Skip(1);
    StringBuilder full = new StringBuilder(part);
    return full.Append(RemoveQuotes(afterIgnore)).ToString();
}
```