# c# - How do i remove a variable part of a string?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I would like to remove part of a string. It would have to match  "/*/cms/" (without the quotes). * would be a wildcard equaling anything except a / key. The string could have more than one match to be removed.

This would have to be done in c#. I think this can be done with a regex? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to match that is `/[^/]*/cms/`, used like this: `new Regex("/[^/]*/cms/").Replace(yourString, "")`

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.Replace("/some example text/cms/;/some more text/cms/text/cms", "/[^/]+/cms/", "")
```

Use `/[^/]+/cms/` if something must be between the first and second `/`'s, use `/[^/]*/cms/` if `//cms/` is a valid match.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Hacking the example quickly:

```
string pattern = "/[^/]+/cms/";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462646/how-can-i-remove-quoted-string-literals-from-a-string-in-c/4462673#4462673) question will help you. Ensure that you use the `Regex.Replace()` method to do the pattern matching and replacement.